# OSX Mavericks VPN PPTP

Tags: macos, vpn, pptp

I have an issue with vpn pptp connection on my macbook. The latest version of Mavericks is installed. The log (/var/log/ppp.log) is provided below

```
Fri Feb 21 20:08:33 2014 : Warning: can't open options file /etc/ppp/peers/int: Permission denied
Fri Feb 21 20:08:33 2014 : publish_entry SCDSet() failed: Success!
Fri Feb 21 20:08:33 2014 : publish_entry SCDSet() failed: Success!
Fri Feb 21 20:08:33 2014 : Fatal signal 13
Fri Feb 21 20:08:33 2014 : can't talk to PPPController : Broken pipe
```

File is not exists on my system, I had tried to create it also had changed chmod

```
/etc/ppp/peers/int
```

This VPN works properly on my iphone and windows pc.

Also I don't have any problems with connection using command line:

```
sudo networksetup -connectpppoeservice int
```

I don't have possibility to check other VPN types, but I had tried to connect to PPTP servers on Windows and Linux OS.

Answer (score 1):

i ran also in the exact same issue. Apple Forums did not really lead to a solution.

Rebooting on the other hand solved the issue completely.